# Grok is not returning valid JSON

Tags: java, json, grok

following log line give invalid json for grok pattern

```
 2021-06-15 10:05:55:617|[28]|test-backend|ERROR|STDOUT|test|test-service|abcd1234|API_CALL|test|Error|Controller {"testtag":["test error message"]}
```

Grok

```
(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}.%{NONNEGINT})\|\[(?<thread>[^\]]+)\]\|%{IPORHOST:pod_instance}\|%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\|%{GREEDYDATA}\|%{GREEDYDATA:application}\|%{GREEDYDATA:microservice}\|%{UUID:uuid}\|(?<message_type>[^|]*)\|(?<message>[^|]*)(?<options>(?:(\|.*)|(|AD.*)|()))
```

and option tag return as

```
 "options": [
[
  "|Error|Controller {"testtag":["test error message"]}"
 ...
```

entire json is get invalidated because of that. I want that generate as a valid json is there any way to add escape for additional quote `"` in json string something like belo

```
"|Error|Controller {\"testtag\":[\"test error message\"]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the combination of **GROK** and **KV** filter to filter out the log message.

First use the below grok pattern to filter the log message into different fields:

```
(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}.%{NONNEGINT})\|\[(?<thread>[^\]]+)\]\|%{IPORHOST:pod_instance}\|%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\|%{GREEDYDATA}\|%{GREEDYDATA:application}\|%{GREEDYDATA:microservice}\|%{UUID:uuid}\|(?<message_type>[^|]*)\|(?<message>[^|]*)\|(?<message_error>[^|]*)\|(?<message_error_part>[^|]*) \{%{GREEDYDATA:tagmsg}\}
```

Now, we will use **KV** to filter field `tag` which contains the json part.

```
filter {
      kv {
        source => "tagmsg",
        value_split => ":",
        trim_value => "\[\]"
      }
    }
```

Please refer [KV Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv) for more FIlter configuration options.